# запрос обрабатывается 13 секунд

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select month, p_id, sum(day_kavicent) as k 
from cms_persons_diary_2016 
group by month, p_id
```

группировка по месяцам и юзерам

индекс (`month, p_id, day_kavicent`) количество строк 3800000

время отработки 7-13 секунд.
в профайлинге только сендинг дата занимает все время.
в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: сколько данных на клиент возвращается то? если все время уходит на отправку данных, дак может проблема в том, что выбирается слишком много данных, которые медленно отправляются на клиент? или я вас неправильно понял?

Comment: по полю `p_id ` есть индексация?

Comment: А если индекс будет только по двум полям (month, p_id)?

Comment: то отрабатывается медленне на 1 секунду

Comment: output 49 000 строк и так и должно быть. Цель сгрупировать очки каждого юзера по дате и юзеру.Сейчас запрос обрабатывается 6 секунд и большую часть времени занимает copy from temp table.Если честно доверия к профайлингу нет но временная таблица достаточного объема.Хотелось бы узнать может 6 секунд для 49000 строк это нормально ? или можно что то изменить